# Settingup forms/fields tables for linking data in front end?

Tags: php, mysql, database, schema

I have a question/Answer table which holds values for Days, Months, Weeks, Years and various other data like this:

**tbl_Questions**
question_id
question

**tbl_answers**
answer_id
answer

**tbl_QA**
qa_id
question_id
answer_id

Sample day would be like:

Question:
23 - Months

Answers:
234 - Jan
235 - Feb
236 - March...

QA:
100 - 23  - 234
101 - 23  - 235
102 - 23  - 236
...

All this is fine but I am lost on how do i pull (reference) this data into the front end forms? Obviously the months will be a drop down List on the site, so I want the drop down to pull in these values and I want these IDs to be written to the user table when they select a 'month' value for any question that has month. This way I can do analytic by having all data linked from 1 place. Any guidelines on how to go about this? Using mysql and php.

---

2) For months, do i need to store jan, feb, etc in seperate rows or can i seralize all data into one cell like "Jan", "Feb"...  My concern is i need to do search on many of these lookup values so i dont know if i can do it within serialized text?

Answer (score 0):

Pull the data from the database using a while loop and mysql_fetch_assoc in order to iterate over each question

```
<select>
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) {
   $value = $row['question_id'];
   $month = $row['question'];
   echo "<option value='$value'>$month</option>";
}
</select>
```

The $result variables obviously being your DB query.